# How do I reverse my insert within a plasmid?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, restriction-enzymes, t7-promoter, vector

I have a plasmid with:

...T7pro. -- RBS -- XBa1 cut site -- **ProDpro. -- RBS -- AmilCP -- T** -- Spe1 cut site -- T...

How do I design primers to reverse the portion in bold, such that the T7 and ProD promoters are on opposite sides of AmilCP? I am finding it difficult to understand how to design the appropriate primers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your 5' primer upstream of ProDpro. with a Spe1 cut site added to the end (plus a few extra random bases to allow for better cutting). Add an Xba1 cut site to the end of the 3' primer, again with a few extra random bases on the end to allow for better cutting.

Amplify the insert, PCR cleanup, digest, cleanup again, and you should be able to easily clone into the Xba1/Spe1 digested vector that has been gel purified.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it helps. As this seems a bit unclear on re-reading this, be sure your cut sites are on the 5' end (beginning) of each primer.

Comment: Also, if you feel an answer properly answers your question, be sure to mark it as the answer so others know that your question has been resolved.